# how can i remove my slideshow width? and how can i add more number of picture in my slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can i remove my slideshow width?  and how can i  add more number of picture in my slideshow

[image: here is the screenshot]

i want to increase my slideshow width, and increase number of picture of myslideshow, slideshow is writtern in java, css and html.
my pics size is 1200x300.
i tried to add width in css but width increased just right side, my pic does not fit in center please help me experts.
Help Help Help
Help Help Help
Help Help Help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .mySlides {
      display: none
    }
    /* Slideshow container */
    
    .slideshow-container {
      max-width: 1200px;
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;
    }
    /* Caption text */
    
    .text {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 8px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
    
    .numbertext {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-size: 12px;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    .active {
      background-color: #717171;
    }
    /* Fading animation */
    
    .fade {
      -webkit-animation-name: fade;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
      animation-name: fade;
      animation-duration: 1.5s;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes fade {
      from {
        opacity: .4
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes fade {
      from {
        opacity: .4
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1
      }
    }
    /* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
      .text {
        font-size: 11px
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext"></div>
      <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-LMLb-SRggk8/WdfQDgzmHYI/AAAAAAAAByc/UWQgh2DqSdAY5esr3-i5qmRYDFVuTh7zACLcBGAs/s1600/Flag%2B1200x300.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext"></div>
      <img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-lbgXjiKwfss/WdfQufxdrsI/AAAAAAAAByk/A8oJ9b3nMugIs6LIgjv04qCHAfrO-NXrACLcBGAs/s1600/Animation%2BLight%2BHouse.gif" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext"></div>
      <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6RWJYpjHqFE/WdfQ8S9RWrI/AAAAAAAAByo/OflSPE6aAKQpvWjfNUS3-lrddygVFaL6QCLcBGAs/s1600/outer%2Bspace%2Bnight%2Bstars.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <br>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
  </div>

  <script>
    var slideIndex = 0;
    showSlides();

    function showSlides() {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      slideIndex++;
      if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
      setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Remove margin from body.

Comment: i can't understand bro, plz explain

Comment: Check out my answer with working demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the margin in the body and add the `min-width: 100%;` to the `.slideshow-container`.

For adding more slide just duplicate this code.

```
<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext"></div>
  <img src="my-image.jpg"> <!-- remove the width property from all image tag. -->
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

There is no magical width property that will set the image width to 100% you need to set the width of the container of the image and the image will expand accordingly.

Also, increase the number of `<span class="dot"></span>` element as you increase the slides. Because it depends on the number of slides else it will stop the js code and throw an error.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    
    .widget {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    
    .mySlides {
      display: none
    }
    /* Slideshow container */
    
    .slideshow-container {
      min-width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;
    }
    /* Caption text */
    
    .text {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 8px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
    
    .numbertext {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-size: 12px;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    .active {
      background-color: #717171;
    }
    /* Fading animation */
    
    .fade {
      -webkit-animation-name: fade;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
      animation-name: fade;
      animation-duration: 1.5s;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes fade {
      from {
        opacity: .4
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes fade {
      from {
        opacity: .4
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1
      }
    }
    /* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
      .text {
        font-size: 11px
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext"></div>
      <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-LMLb-SRggk8/WdfQDgzmHYI/AAAAAAAAByc/UWQgh2DqSdAY5esr3-i5qmRYDFVuTh7zACLcBGAs/s1600/Flag%2B1200x300.jpg" style="width: 100%">
      <div class="text"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext"></div>
      <img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-lbgXjiKwfss/WdfQufxdrsI/AAAAAAAAByk/A8oJ9b3nMugIs6LIgjv04qCHAfrO-NXrACLcBGAs/s1600/Animation%2BLight%2BHouse.gif" style="width: 100%">
      <div class="text"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext"></div>
      <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6RWJYpjHqFE/WdfQ8S9RWrI/AAAAAAAAByo/OflSPE6aAKQpvWjfNUS3-lrddygVFaL6QCLcBGAs/s1600/outer%2Bspace%2Bnight%2Bstars.jpg" style="width: 100%">
      <div class="text"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext"></div>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-1200-300-3.jpg" style="width: 100%">
      <div class="text"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext"></div>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-1200-300-5.jpg" style="width: 100%">
      <div class="text"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <br>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <!-- Increase the dots as you increase the slides -->
  </div>

  <script>
    var slideIndex = 0;
    showSlides();

    function showSlides() {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      slideIndex++;
      if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
      setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: when i add the div for more pic, it added successfully, but not starting after the slideshow end

Comment: and i added the min-width code but did not make any difference

Comment: But the width issue is fixed in the code snippet run the code above.

Comment: No Btother, I pasted your code but results are the same

Comment: Brother Please help me, i am very upset

Comment: @Faisal after doing some tweaks the issues are fixed.

Comment: Btother i pasted this code in my blog, it gives the same results

Comment: Did you do a hard reload for cache busting? Ctrl + f5

Comment: @Faisal Now I fixed it give it a shot. If you want to remove more padding then you need to add more property but the UI will look ugly.

Comment: Glad that you fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing:border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;}
.mySlides {display:none}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}



.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext"></div>
  <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-LMLb-SRggk8/WdfQDgzmHYI/AAAAAAAAByc/UWQgh2DqSdAY5esr3-i5qmRYDFVuTh7zACLcBGAs/s1600/Flag%2B1200x300.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>


<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext"></div>
  <img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-lbgXjiKwfss/WdfQufxdrsI/AAAAAAAAByk/A8oJ9b3nMugIs6LIgjv04qCHAfrO-NXrACLcBGAs/s1600/Animation%2BLight%2BHouse.gif" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>


<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext"></div>
  <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6RWJYpjHqFE/WdfQ8S9RWrI/AAAAAAAAByo/OflSPE6aAKQpvWjfNUS3-lrddygVFaL6QCLcBGAs/s1600/outer%2Bspace%2Bnight%2Bstars.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Btother i pasted this code in my blog, it gives the same results